# Count values without having to specify each

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I need to count how many times ids repeats, without having to specify each id. In my case I need it for know how many customers come 3 times or more in a month. Here is an example of where Im getting the data from:

```
customers|   id
------------------
person 1 | 2433340
person 2 | 3457548
person 3 | 3457584
person 4 | 4343218
person 4 | 4343218
person 4 | 4343218
person 3 | 3457584
```

And this one is the one that I need to fill:

```
Times that customers come
--------------------------
1 time  | 2
2 times | 1
3 times | 1
```

Comment: I posted an answer on here about top 5 or top 10 which is similar to what you are looking for. Edit it to meet your needs.

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Which of the two are you actually using?

Comment: sorry Im using google sheets

Comment: @SolarMike I tried your formula but I dont get it working, "=if(countif(xxx)>=1,1,0)", Im replacing the xxx with the data range

Answer (score 1):

I have used:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(B2:B,"Select Count(B) where B is not null group by B label Count(B) 'Times'"),"Select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

Comment: Im doing the exactly the same as you did but gives my ERROR, do I have to change something on your formula? (Im putting the values exacly in same position)

Comment: Only reason I can think of is that your locale requires the semi-colon to seperate functions/parameters isntead of the comma @Cattivellio. If that still does not work, just share the sample sheet.

Comment: oh you were right was the comma thing. This is fine right know, but will be better if this was a one-cell formula, and not a query or array, do you know if is possible?

edit: the formula will take the range and the times the user wants to get

Comment: A one cell formula?

Comment: with one-cell formula, I mean that only change tha value of the cell where you place the formula, little bit confusing, a very basic example of what I call a one-cell formula its the SUM() formula, it just change the cell where you place it, none arrays or lists

Comment: It's possible but it does make no sense to join all these items in a single cell to be honest.

Comment: I think you didnt get what I tried to say. Now I have a better way to explain: I want the user to fill the amount cells bellow <Times> and google sheets should just fill the cells bellow <count> using the range of <Id> and the <Times> that user input (using your pic as reference)

Answer (score 0):

I would work with a helper column (D) to count visits per person. Then it is pretty easy to count the "x times".

Values in column F are numbers formatted as "0 "time""

[image]

Comment: this work for me, but I think there is other way around without a helper, as person above did